# RxJava, android - синхронизировать ответы от двух Observable

Tags: android, алгоритм, rxjava

Пререквизиты:

1. При старте приложения происходит получения токена для push-рассылки(Firebase)
2. В стартовой `Activity` происходит запрос на сервер для получения `id` сессии. Запрос через `retrofit` с ответом в виде `Observable`

Необходимо реализовать такой алгоритм:

После того, как получен `id` сессии, необходимо отправить на сервер push-токен.

Нюансы:

1. Токен может придти раньше, чем запустится запрос сессии.
2. А может и позже.
3. Ожидание получения токена не должно блокировать работу приложения.

Напрашивается `Publisher` с `onNext(token)` в `onTokenRefresh` и подписка на него в `onComplete` запроса `id`, но см. п 1)

Как вариант, в `onComplete` смотреть, получен ли токен и, если нет, подписываться на паблишера. Но все равно возможна ситуация, когда токен придет между проверкой и подпиской - процесс повиснет навсегда.

Сначала подписаться, потом проверять и, если что отписываться - тоже как то не комильфо.

**Как бы вы подошли к этой задаче?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
Observable.zip(tokenObservable, idObservable, Pair::create)
        .flatMap(pair -> api.sendToken(pair.first, pair.second))
        .subscribe(result -> Log.d(TAG, "Token sent successfully"));
```

или даже так:

```
Observable.zip(tokenObservable, idObservable, api::sendToken)
        .flatMap(sendTokenObservable -> sendTokenObservable)
        .subscribe(result -> Log.d(TAG, "Token sent successfully"));
```

Хотя это если количество параметров и их типы во всех используемых методах апи хорошо сочетаются.

Если токен может придти до выполнения этой конструкции, то при создании tokenObservable надо добавить в конец `.replay(1).refCount()`. Это позволит получить значение не только подписчикам уже подписанным на этот Observable на момент получения токена, но и всем будущим подписчикам.

Если подробнее, то [replay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html) сохраняет последние n значений и "перепроигрывает" их для всех новых подписчиков:
[image: Replay]

Но при этом этот оператор возвращает Connectable Observable, а не обычный Observable. Connectable Observable отличаются от обычных тем что работать начинают не после того как на них подпишутся, а после того как вызовут метод connect. Нам же нужен обычный Observable, так что выполняем метод [refCount](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html) который преобразует Connectable Observable в обычный Observable.

Comment: Беда в том, что tokenObservable может запустить свой единственный `onNext()` раньше, чем запустится эта конструкция. Так то про zip я знаю

Comment: тогда там где у вас создается tokenObservable добавьте `replay(1).refCount()`, тогда если значение будет получено до подписки, оно всё равно уйдет подписчику.

Comment: Я буду дико благодарен, если вы простыми словами распишите, что делает replay(1) и refCount(). А то я уже весь мозг сломал.

Comment: Дополнил ответ подробным описанием. PS: наконец то и сам разобрался с этим, а то всё было лень подробно почитать, обходился примерным пониманием.